# shell script read command is not waiting along with ssh

Tags: shell

Hi all I am new to shell scripting and please help me in this situation.
I have created a shell script named ./remote1 which looks like below.

> # ./remote1 file
>   ssh username@x.x.x.x  'bash -s' < ./createdir

Here 'createdir' is another file i had created which is given below

> # ./createdir file
>   echo "give directory name"
>   read name
>   mkdir ~/$name

If I run the ./createdir alone in my machine, it will execute without any problem.

If I execute ./remote1, it will not wait for input the data for the 'read' command.Please anyone could help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/259808/shell-script-read-is-not-waiting-with-ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for you great support. 
But i have solved my issue.

> # ./remote1 file
>   ssh username@x.x.x.x 'echo "give directory name";
>   read name;
>   mkdir ~/$name

This solved my issue simply.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the remote `read`. Why don't you execute the read on the local machine, rather than remotely?

For example, you can change your script to:

```
# ./remote1 file
echo "give directory name"
read name

ssh username@x.x.x.x "bash -s" < ./createdir "$name"
```

Comment: That is an option.But if there is any solution then that would be better.